# Joining an array of words / phrases with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
irb(main):001:0> a =  ["global climate change", "calamity", "glaciers", "new york times"]
  => ["global climate change", "calamity", "glaciers", "new york times"]
irb(main):002:0> a.join(', ')
  => "global climate change, calamity, glaciers, new york times"
```

I need the result to be

```
  => "global climate change", "calamity", "glaciers", "new york times"
```

Ideas?  A one-liner would be ideal.

Comment: `result = '"' + a.join('", "') + '"'` ? Or in other words: `result = "\"#{a.join('", "')}\""`

Comment: What data type are you expecting that result to be?? A single string, or an Array?

Comment: do you need this as an output? Because you couldn't store your needed result in a variable, as it's neither an `array` nor a `string`

Comment: it's... a collection of strings.

Comment: When I hear "collection of strings" I think "array of strings", which is exactly what your first example is...

Comment: An `array` ist usually used to collect multiple objects...

Comment: ha, @DylanMarkow, yeah... I'm doing something like this.  `Category.where("name IN ('global climate change', 'calamity', 'glaciers', 'new york times')")`

Comment: queries are capable of asking `name IN #{Array}`, so I guess you can work with your `array` after all :)

Comment: I'd like to think so... it's not working for me, Champ

Comment: Check this out: http://www.cowboycoded.com/2010/04/20/sql-in-command-in-rails-find-using-an-array/

Comment: @TheChamp, that works with Id only, i think.  you can even more easily say `Widget.find([1,2,3,4,5])`

Comment: See my answer, works fine with strings aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to pass arrays of options to a query via ActiveRecord is just to use query parameters:

```
a = ["global climate change", "calamity", "glaciers", "new york times"]
Category.where("name IN (?)", a)
# Generated query:
# Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE (name in ('global climate change','calamity','glaciers','new york times'))
```

You don't have to do anything special to transform it into a valid SQL fragment. You should specifically avoid formatting strings as SQL fragments, as without careful sanitization, you may open up SQL injection vulnerabilities in your application.

Comment: This is the way i wanted to do it!!  haha.  I kept getting this, though `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE (name IN 'global climate change','calamity','glaciers','melting ice','nasa','new york times')`

Comment: Make sure you wrap your ? in parentheses. Your query should be `name in (?)`, not `name in ?`.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!

Comment: I've done so many other LIKE and IN queries with just the ?.  Should you always use the (?), or just when dealing with arrays?

Comment: Just when dealing with arrays.

Comment: I think it's better to avoid SQL syntax when possible. After all, we are trying to abstract from the underlying database with ActiveRecord. In that spirit, try this syntax: `Category.where(name: my_array)`. Then you don't have to worry about the specifics of the SQL and the parentheses and all that.

Comment: Heh, yeah. Old habits die hard. But agreed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using arrays in a query is very simple:

```
arr = ["global climate change", "calamity", "glaciers", "new york times"]
Category.where(:name => arr)
```

There is absolutely no need to generate some weird string ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
a =  ["global climate change", "calamity", "glaciers", "new york times"]
=> ["global climate change", "calamity", "glaciers", "new york times"]
%Q!"#{a.join('", "')}"!
=> "\"global climate change\", \"calamity\", \"glaciers\", \"new york times\""
a.map{|e| "\"#{e}\""}.join(', ')
=> "\"global climate change\", \"calamity\", \"glaciers\", \"new york times\""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ['bob', 'bill']
new_array_string = array.map { |name| "'#{name}'" }.join(',')
=> "'bob', 'bill'"
User.where("name IN (#{new_array_string})")
```